thermal printing problem with image on ios device
I am trying to print image in thermal pos. There is no problem on the android side, but the printing process on the ios side is incomplete. It print only helf of image.
Packages : print_bluetooth_thermal, esc_pos_utils_plus , widgets_to_image

final Uint8List? imageBytes = await controller.capture(pixelRatio: 1);
final profile = await CapabilityProfile.load();
final generator = Generator(PaperSize.mm58, profile);

List<int> bytes = [];
bytes += generator.reset();

var image = img.decodeImage(imageBytes);

if (Platform.isIOS) {
      final resizedImage = img.copyResize(image!, width: image.width ~/ 1.3, height: image.height ~/ 1.3, interpolation: img.Interpolation.nearest);
      final byteString = Uint8List.fromList(img.encodeJpg(resizedImage));
      image = img.decodeImage(byteString);
      bytes += generator.imageRaster(image!,align: PosAlign.center);
}else{
      bytes +=generator.imageRaster(image!);
}
bytes += generator.feed(2);

var printing = await PrintBluetoothThermal.writeBytes(bytes);
print(printing); // donot show any message


Try maintainAspect: false in img.copyResize().
And this also bytes += generator.imageRaster(resizedImage, align: PosAlign.center);

In generator.imageRaster(resizedImage, align: PosAlign.center) doesn't hav param  maintainAspect

No… it will in copyresize function

Yes, in copyResize I put already but it still the same result
